# AWS S3 file upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, acl

I want to upload an image to s3 bucket without making my bucket public.

1. I have tried this bucket policy
2. and blocked all public access[image]

3. here is the code i tried

```
const s3Params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET,
    Key: Date.now().toString() + ".jpg",
    ContentType: file.mimetype,
    ACL: "public-read"
}
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: awsConfig.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: awsConfig.secretAccessKey,
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3()
s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", s3Params, async (err, signuedUrl) => {

    console.log('errros are', err)
    console.log('data i s', signuedUrl)
   
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log('xhr is ', xhr)
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                // The file could not be uploaded.
                // rejvoipEventsChannelect();
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.open("PUT", signuedUrl)
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Amz-ACL", "public-read")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.mimetype)
    xhr.send(file.data);

})
```

here is the code using aws-sdk

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
   accessKeyId: awsConfig.accessKeyId,
   secretAccessKey: awsConfig.secretAccessKey,
});
const options = {
   Bucket: BUCKET,
   ACL: awsConfig.ACL,
   Key:  'test.jpg',
   Body: file.data,
};
s3.upload(options, function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
       throw err;
   }
   cb(`${data.Location}`)
});
```

4. Here is the response

```
xhr is  {
 UNSENT: 0,
 OPENED: 1,
 HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2,
 LOADING: 3,
 DONE: 4,
 readyState: 4,
 onreadystatechange: [Function],
 responseText: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
   '<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message></Error>',
 responseXML: '',
 status: 403,
 statusText: null,
 withCredentials: false,
 open: [Function],
 setDisableHeaderCheck: [Function],
 setRequestHeader: [Function],
 getResponseHeader: [Function],
 getAllResponseHeaders: [Function],
 getRequestHeader: [Function],
 send: [Function],
 handleError: [Function],
 abort: [Function],
 addEventListener: [Function],
 removeEventListener: [Function],
 dispatchEvent: [Function]
}
```

5. Same code will work and object will be uploaded to bucket if i uncheck "block all public access" checkbox from the image

Comment: did you check if "user , (accessKeyId , secretkey)  " has permission to upload?

Comment: is the request sent from a client side js or node js application? Asking because of the `XMLHttpRequest` usage.

Comment: these are keys of owners account.

Comment: i'm sending this request from node js server because i need to use signed URL . so i used XMLHttpRequest.  If there is a better way to use signed url then i can use that as well..

Comment: Why are you using a signed URL? Are you uploading from the server to S3, or are you creating a URL for your web users to upload to S3? If it is being uploaded from the server, then you can upload directly without using a signed URL.

Comment: Also, why are you setting the ACL to `public-read`? Are you wanting the object to be publicly accessible?

Comment: You can use `aws-sdk` to upload to s3 directly. `s3.upload(params).then(response => {}).catch(err => {});` No need of generating presigned url.

Comment: I am uploading user profile image from node js server. i also tried aws.S3(params).upload() , but i got same access denied if public access is blocked